# Is there a way to "pivot" a ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableSet<String>>?

Tags: guava

I have a ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableSet<String>>.  Is there an easy way to "pivot" this kid or do I have to code it myself?  I am trying to figure out the best way to view...

```
{
  type1=[FieldA, FieldB, FieldC],
  type2=[FieldB, FieldC, FieldD],
  type3=[FieldC, FieldD, FieldE]
}
```

...as...

```
{
  FieldA=[type1],
  FieldB=[type1, type2], 
  FieldC=[type1, type2, type3], 
  FieldD=[type1, type2],
  FieldE=[type3]
}
```

Does MultiMap solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like MultiMap is the way to go.  The [ImmutableMultiMap#inverse()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMultimap.html#inverse%28%29) method is what I was looking for:

```
ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, String> builder = new ImmutableMultimap.Builder<String, String>();
builder.putAll( "type1", Arrays.asList( "FieldA", "FieldB", "FieldC") );
builder.putAll( "type2", Arrays.asList( "FieldB", "FieldC", "FieldD") );
builder.putAll( "type3", Arrays.asList( "FieldC", "FieldD", "FieldE") );
ImmutableMultimap<String, String> typesToFields = builder.build();
ImmutableMultimap<String, String> fieldsToTypes = typesToFields.inverse();

System.out.println( "typesToFields: " + typesToFields );
System.out.println( "fieldsToTypes: " + fieldsToTypes );
```

...produces...

```
typesToFields: {type1=[FieldA, FieldB, FieldC], type2=[FieldB, FieldC, FieldD], type3=[FieldC, FieldD, FieldE]}
fieldsToTypes: {FieldA=[type1], FieldB=[type1, type2], FieldC=[type1, type2, type3], FieldD=[type2, type3], FieldE=[type3]}
```